# Connect to 2 different mongodb databases in Nuxt 3 / Vue 3 Application

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

I am using NuxtJS 3 and Vue 3 and I am connecting to a single mongoDb database without problem. I would like to connect at the same time to another database, where I will store and retrieve data.

My question is: How can I implement that and selecting each database in the server routes?

I am using mongoose!

Comment: Please show some of your file structure so that I can help more! Can the other data not live in a separate collection? If you absolutely have to use two separate DBs instead of two collections, you can add the second uri to your .env file and interchange the URI when you connect mongoose.

Comment: @Kyrony: I added a comment with the code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for elaborating on your question, after making both connections to mongoose, you can use mongoose.connections to differentiate between your databases!

ex:

```
mongoose.connections[0] // Points to the first connection (mongoose.connect(config.mongodbUri))

mongoose.connections[1] // Point to your admin connection (mongoose.connect(config.mongodbUriAdmin))
```

To simplify this further, I would create a variable that holds these values so that you can use them in your routes without repeating code!

Like this:

```
const admindb = mongoose.connections[1] // Admin Database
```

Here's a link to the documentation !
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#Mongoose.prototype.connections

Answer (score -1):

.env file:

```
MONGODB_URI=mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster>.puuwipp.mongodb.net/<db1>
MONGODB_URI_ADMIN=mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster>.puuwipp.mongodb.net/<db2>
```

nuxt.config.ts:

```
    runtimeConfig: {
    mongodbUri: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
    mongodbUriAdmin: process.env.MONGODB_URI_ADMIN,
  }
```

server.index.ts:

```
  export default async (_nitroApp: Nitro) => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig();

  try {
    mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
    await mongoose.connect(config.mongodbUri);
    console.log("DB connection established");
    await mongoose.connect(config.mongodbUriAdmin);
    console.log("ADMIN DB connection established");
  } catch (e) {
    return e.message;
  }
};
```

But I do not know, how to define which db to use in mongoose models / in the server requests